# How can I get JavaDoc to display the values of static final variables?

Tags: javadoc

How can I get JavaDoc to display the values of static final variables (when those variables are set before the constructor) ?    The JavaDoc currently shows the variable name but not the value of it, which I would like to reveal to readers of my doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it as follows:

```
/**
 * DEFAULT_ENV = {@value #DEFAULT_ENV}
 */
public static final String DEFAULT_ENV = "undefined";
```